# How to combine these google script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm new to coding, and I got a lot of similar code in a section of my google script. Is there a way to combine all these?

```
e.range.offset(0, -7).setValue("");
e.range.offset(0, -6).setValue("");
e.range.offset(0, -5).setValue("");
e.range.offset(0, -4).setValue("");
e.range.offset(0, -3).setValue("");
e.range.offset(0, -2).setValue("");
e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue("");
e.range.offset(0, 2).setValue("");
e.range.offset(0, 3).setValue("");
e.range.offset(0, 4).setValue("");
e.range.offset(0, 5).setValue("");
e.range.offset(0, 6).setValue("");
```

Notice that it does not have "-1" or "0".
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
e.range.offset(0,-7,1,7).setValue('');
e.range.offset(0,1,1,6).setValue('');
```

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset,-numrows,-numcolumns

Comment: It works well, thank you! I understand how to do it now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please take a moment and read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)